# How many times can you use a weapon in one round?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

So I'm playing a D&D 5e homebrew campaign and while I was in a battle in one round I did this.

1. Move 15 feet (from basic 35 feet)
2. Put my light crossbow away
3. Drew a longsword with two hands (as a part of the attack)
4. Attacked an orc with that longsword with two hands

I'm not sure how many times I can interact with an object and I searched the *player's handbook* and it only says that you can draw your sword as a part of the attack? And I'm not sure that you can put your crossbow away too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interact with one object *for free* on your turn, any other interaction requires you to use your action. As per page 190 of the PHB:

> #### Other activities on your turn
>
> [...] You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action. For example. you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe, or **you could draw your weapon as part of the same action you use to attack.** If you want to interact with a second object, you need to use your action...

And on the next page are some other examples of "things you can do in tandem with your movement and action" which includes drawing **or** sheathing a [weapon].

In your specific example, sheathing your crossbow would be your free interaction with objects and you'd have to use your action to draw your sword which means you wouldn't be able to attack with it.

Comment: Note: you can get special class abilities that allow you to use a weapon for attacks more often, or that give extra actions that can be used for drawing or sheathing a weapon.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you can drop an object for free.  One could drop their crossbow then draw a sword to attack.

Comment: @JPicasso I have scoured the rules and have not been able to find one that says you can drop an object for free. It is a common, indeed nearly universal, assumption. And it's one that makes sense to me too!